# Markups and display in the same file : XHTM?

Tags: html, xml, database, xhtml, display

I’d like to have a file containing both structured data XML) and the information to display it by a browser (HTML).
Example: a pretty web page made of one photo and its EXIF data, displayable by a web broser and from which data can be imported by something understanding XML.

Is this XHTML ?
(I understand its not and XHTML is just a stricter way to write HTML)

If it is not XHTML, do you have an idea on how to achieve that ? Thanks!

Comment: Ehm, you can put CSS, scripts and even image data inline in a HTML file (or an XHTML file), but I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve. Can you elaborate?

Comment: Or, I think you are talking about [XSLT](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XSLT), right?

Comment: To rephrase what I am looking for: a way to make XML readable by a browser and humanly understandable.

XSLT seems actually very close even if it requires two documents.

I don't know from where I got the idea that XHTML was a fusion of XML and HTML and was a way to transmit data in a humanly readable document (giving to the same document the "power" of XML and HTML at the same time) , but being able to do so would be a great ! Imagine a document that can be read by you recipient and by an application.